# Can't access sublayer after adding a UIView into current UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, cashapelayer

I'm drawing a bunch of CAShapeLayer so I need to detect which one I'm touching so I use this

```
if let sublayers = self.layer.sublayers as? [CAShapeLayer]{ //get all CAShape and stored as an array
            print("loop sublayer")
            for layer in sublayers{ // go through each CAShape
                print("loop layer")
                if let path = layer.path, path.contains(currentPanPoint) { // if there is a path at that point then return, else create a path
                    print("detecting")
                    startPointOfTouchedRuler = detectWhichRuler(layer: layer)
                    if startPointOfTouchedRuler != zeroPoint{
                        //  drawCircle(point: startPointOfTouchedRuler)
                        break
                    }else{
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Now I want to add an UIView whenever I create a CAShapeLayer to manage and move them easier, I use this to add a new Uiview at CAShapeLayer Location:

```
  func createUIViewOutSideRuler(startPoint:CGPoint, currentPoint:CGPoint, angle: CGFloat){
        let viewWidth = distanceFromTwoPoints(startPoint, currentPoint)
        print(viewWidth)
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:currentPoint.x, y: currentPoint.y , width:  viewWidth, height: dotLineSize * 3))
        view.backgroundColor = .orange
        view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle);
        
        self.addSubview(view)
    }
```

After new UIview is added, the loop to get which CAShapeLayer won't fire at all, the command line doesn't print `print("loop sublayer")`

P/S: It applies to Label, Button, etc as well. And if I `print(self.layer.sublayers as? [CAShapeLayer])` after adding an `UIView` `UIButton`, it returns `nil`

---

Comment: Could you check that `self.layer.sublayers` is not empty? If it's not, your line is nil because of the cast. => `let sublayers = self.layer.sublayers.flatMap { $0 as? CAShapeLayer }` instead? All the sublayers might not be a `CAShapeLayer`, but another layer?

Comment: `self.layer.sublayers` is not empty but when I make it as CAShapeLayer, it return `nil`.


`let sublayers = self.layer.sublayers.flatMap { $0 as? CAShapeLayer }` got warning 
`Cast from '[CALayer]' to unrelated type 'CAShapeLayer' always fails` and also return `nil`

Comment: "but when I make it as CAShapeLayer" with the `flatMap` as I suggested? because if it's like your code, then it will fail obviously. Also, you added a subview? But then, the shape layer is on that view, not on the initial one? Edit: I meant `compactMap()`, not `flatMap()`

Comment: I've tried, `flatMap` and didn't work. My new shape layer is still on the initial one, I've just create a new UIView and haven't do anything with it.

Comment: I meant `compactMap`, not `flatMap()`, my bad.

Comment: Worked perfectly, though I'm still a bit confusing but I'll figure out why (I'm still new). Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick explanation:**

When you do `self.layer.sublayers as? [CAShapeLayer]`, you are supposing that ALL `self.layer.sublayers` are of type `CAShapeLayer`. But, are you sure about that, who told you this? There are other kind of `CALayer`, and default components might come with some already. That's why it's failing. The idea, is with to use `compactMap()` to keep only the `CAShapeLayer`:

```
let sublayers = self.layer.sublayers.compactMap { $0 as? [CAShapeLayer] }
```

**Detailed explanation:**

```
if let sublayers = self.layer.sublayers as? [CAShapeLayer] {} else {}
```

The `else` is called because `self.layer.sublayers` is not cartable into, it's not a [CAShapeLayer]. In our case, they are layers, so it means that not all sublayer is a `CAShapeLayer`.
So, let's keep only the `CAShapeLayer`, and forget about the other one (`CAGradientLayer`, `CALayer`, etc.).
For that, we can use `compactMap()`.

```
self.layer.sublayers.compactMap { aSublayer in
 
}
```

The closure logic is simple:
The array is iterated. On each iteration, the item is called `aSublayer`. We do whatever we want, and we return a transformed value if needed, an Int, etc.
If we don't want to keep the transformed value, we return nil, and then it will be skipped.

Since we want to keep only the sublayers which are a `CAShapeLayer`, we can use a simple cast on them:

```
if let aSubLayerAsShapeLayer = aSubLayer as? CAShapeLayer {
    return aSubLayerAsShapeLayer
} else { //We won't keep it
    return nil
}
```

Which is equivalent to

```
return aSubLayer as? CAShapeLayer
```

Then, with more simplification (Implicit Returns from Single-Expression Closures, `Shorthand Argument Names`, more info on the [doc](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html)), we get:

```
let sublayers = self.layer.sublayers.compactMap { $0 as? [CAShapeLayer] }
```

Also, since it's "sure" to have an array (might be empty), it's not an optional anymore, we remove the `if let` into a `let`.